# Click axis of plot - output axis value to cell

Tags: excel, vba, plot, figure

I am wondering if anyone knows a way in excel using VBA or any other way in excel to:

Interactively click on the x-axis of a figure plotted in excel and and that x-axis value will be outputted to a cell.

Anyone have any ideas? i am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Not a particularly easy task...

If you create an event handler for when you seelct chart/chart axes, that would get you started. Put this in the Workbook code module. When the file is opened, `Cht` will be set according to the `Workbook_Open` event.  Then the `Private Sub Cht_Select...` will run any time the user selects the chart. If the selected part is an axis, it will display a message box.  You will need to come up with a way to determine the cursor position relative to the axis and do some math to attempt to calculate the axis-value.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Cht As Chart
Private Sub Cht_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, _
    ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)

    If ElementID = xlAxis Then
    MsgBox "Call your macro here to identify cursor position in chart..."
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set Cht = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Cht = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart
End Sub
```

There is some information about getting the mouse cursor position, here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152969

You would then need to get the axis position & length and do some simple math to to calculate the axis-value where the cursor is.

Here is a slightly modified version which you could put in a standard module, to return the XY coordinates in an array. It's up to you to figure out how to use these with the chart axis object, min/max, length, left & top values in order to calculate (or approximate) the axis-value of the cursor when the axis is selected.

```
' Access the GetCursorPos function in user32.dll
  Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
  (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
  ' Access the GetCursorPos function in user32.dll
  Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

  ' GetCursorPos requires a variable declared as a custom data type
  ' that will hold two integers, one for x value and one for y value
  Type POINTAPI
     X_Pos As Long
     Y_Pos As Long
  End Type

  ' This function retrieve cursor position:
  Function Get_Cursor_Pos() As Variant

  ' Dimension the variable that will hold the x and y cursor positions
  Dim Hold As POINTAPI
    Dim xyArray(1) As Variant

  ' Place the cursor positions in variable Hold
  GetCursorPos Hold

  ' Display the cursor position coordinates
    xyArray(0) = Hold.X_Pos
    xyArray(1) = Hold.Y_Pos
    Get_Cursor_Pos = xyArray
  End Function

Sub GetCoordinates()
    Dim xyPosition As Variant

    xyPosition = Get_Cursor_Pos

    Debug.Print xyPosition(0)
    Debug.Print xyPosition(1)

    '### Now that you have the x and y position, you will need to perform some
    ' additional computations with the Axis' .top, .left, and its min/max values
    ' in order to get the approximate axis location where you mouse-clicked it.


End Sub
```